# What's the difference between hostname's show and the hostname on the command line?

Tags: macos

I use `hostname` for checking:

```
aircrafts-MacBook-Pro:~ ldl$ hostname
aircrafts-MacBook-Pro.local
```

there shows `aircrafts-MacBook-Pro.local`.

I want to know the difference between `aircrafts-MacBook-Pro:~ ldl$`'s `aircrafts-MacBook-Pro` and `aircrafts-MacBook-Pro.local`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hostname given by the "hostname" command is the fully qualified hostname (i.e. the full hostname including domains, etc.).

The one displayed in the prompt is shown because your /etc/bashrc file contains the following prompt definition for bash (your shell):

```
PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '
```

The first part of the prompt specification "\h" means that the hostname should be displayed in the prompt - but only the hostname up to the first . (dot).

That's why you see two different things.